# Allow access to local host from specific URL only on Linux

Tags: linux, rest, localhost

I have a REST API listening on the `localhost:8000` and I want it to accept requests from `localhost:5000` only. Is there a way to achieve this on Linux without modifying the API code?

Answer (score 0):

you can use iptables,

but I think it will be easier to use socat like this:

```
socat TCP4:localhost:8000 TCP4:localhost:5000
```

for more information, you can look at this
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10428/simple-way-to-create-a-tunnel-from-one-local-port-to-another

Comment: When I use that command I can continue interacting with localhost:8000 using CURL for example. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: that command simply redirects the requests like curl to 5000 from 8000, Im not sure I understand your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Your REST API probably have it's own mechanism of preventing cross-origin requests and that is the reason why you struggle with connecting those two locations. This problem can't be solved on the Linux level.

First of all, let's explain a few things.
Request's **origin** is defined by the following features:

- *scheme*, which is simply a protocol that you API uses (HTTP or HTTPS)
- *hostname*, which is domain or IP address (in your case it is *localhost*)
- *port*, which is self-explanatory.

So, you want to perform a cross-origin request. In case of the *simple* HTTP request (GET, HEAD or POST request), you have to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on the side of your REST API (*localhost:8000*). For that, check how to set up that header in your specific technology.

Cross-origin requests in your case will be possible if you set this header for the following value:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

You want your localhost to be accessible for the specific URL only - in case of localhost, it is only accessible by the locally running applications. If you deploy your application somewhere in the web, and you want only specific URLs to be able to connect with the REST API, you have to use the following setting of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://foo.example
```

In your case on localhost, that would be:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:5000
```

(I assumed that you use *http* protocol)...

In my opinion, it doesn't make much sense to restrict *localhost* connections this way - `'*'` is good. The only reason I can think of is protection against SSRF attacks, is that the case? (It is only justified if your server is exposed to the web.)

Further resources:

- [Simple cross-origin request documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests)
- [Enabling CORS for REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html)

Comment: Ok, probably I wasn't clear enough explaining my problem. I want my port 8000 to accept requests only from the port 5000. If the port 5001 tries to communicate with the port 8000, I want to forbid the communication. 

This is because I have a REST API listening on the port 8000 (I don't have access to its code), but the only access point to it, should be through the service I have on the port 5000.

Comment: That’s the way Access-Control-Allow-Origin work and the reason of it’s existence. Have you considered for example using proxy on nginx?
You can restrict other ports using iptables, but for example HTTP requests are being sent using ports high, random ports, so you can’t just block some ports and expect it to work